# custom colorization of specific variables in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to highlight the `this` parameter if inserted to a custom method

```
// class Warlock
shout(this: Warlock){
        console.log(this.name)
    }
```

using the scope

```
language    typescript
standard token type Other
foreground  #A9B7C6
background  #2B2B2B
contrast ratio  6.92

semantic token type parameter
modifiers   declaration
foreground  variable.parameter
variable
{ "foreground": "#A9B7C6" }


textmate scopes 

variable.language.this.ts
variable.parameter.ts
meta.parameters.ts
meta.method.declaration.ts
meta.class.ts
source.ts
```

I tried to insert `variable.language.this.ts` into the `settings.JSON`

```
 "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

      // unter Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes
      // auswählen und auf item clicken

      "textMateRules": [



{
  "name": "Other",
  "textmate scopes": "variable.language.this.ts",
  "settings": {
      "foreground": "#DB6EA6", // special case
  }
},

]
```

which gave me this Error `Error :Property textmate scopes is not allowed`

Is there a way to change the color of this specific variable ?

Comment: `this` is **never** an explicit argument of the function, it is an implicit argument determined at the moment of call or bind

Answer (score 0):

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      { "scope":"variable.language.this.ts",
        "settings": {"foreground": "#DB6EA6"}
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: does not change the color, In my settings at least

Comment: @spagalo the `this` in `this.name` changes color

Comment: I already changed the color of `this` keyword, what I want is to change the color of the parameter name if its `this`

Comment: @spagalo `this` is a **keyword** and should NOT be used as a function argument